# JMeter Oauth 1.0 support

Tags: oauth, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to test integration with 3rd party using OAuth **1.0**.

I didn't found any working solution except [OAuthSampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/OAuthSampler/) which mark as deprecated and it states:

> Does not work with JMeter v3.2+.

In JMeter 3.1 Plugin Manager it's marked as deprecated,

Can I still use it in JMeter 3.1 and how? Is there a working solution for sending OAuth 1.0 requests?

Is the main problem of plugin is the use of deprecated [Base64Encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635524/sun-misc-base64decoder-showing-error-in-java-application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth has too many faces therefore I doubt the plugin has ever worked. The best way is reaching out to your application developers, if you will be lucky enough you will get a relevant OAuth client library and code snipped which will be producing the required token. If not - you will at least have [Consumer Key and Consumer Secret](https://hueniverse.com/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iii-security-architecture-e9394f5263b5) which you can use for building up the proper OAuth login sequence and the necessary signature method (as OAuth requests can be signed using [different algorithms](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures))

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) for more detailed explanation, approaches to bypass OAuth login challenges and code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it in JMeter 3.1. The reason many plug-ins do not work with JMeter 3.2 are outlined in [Incompatible changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#Incompatible%20changes) section. Most important reasons are

- Logging changes - this is the most popular reason for plug-ins to break. And looking at OAuthSampler, it seems the likely reason for this plug-in as well.
- Java 8 version requirement. Could be a problem for some libs.

It's also not too hard to convert sampler to be 3.2 friendly (remove logging completely, or change it to use new standard methods), so you could do that from [OAuthSampler source code](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/jmeter-components/blob/master/src/main/java/com/atlantbh/jmeter/plugins/oauth/OAuthSampler.java). You can also use script solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524009/jmeter-oauth-1-0-request)